# What happened to Chay-Ara at the end of season 1 of DC's Legends of Tomorrow?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

At the end of season one after defeating Vandal Savage we never really heard from Chay-Ara anymore. In season two, she ended up just being gone. What happened to her or where did she go?

Comment: https://screenrant.com/legends-tomorrow-hawkman-hawkgirl-arrowverse-exit-reasons/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She left, with Khufu/Torvil/Hawkman, at the end of Season 1, saying that they want to start a new life together now without the imminent threat of being hunted and killed, though they do plan to continue to act as vigilantes in the present.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured it had to be something like that.